# change source of image on button click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am very new to programming. I'm developing a simple windows phone 8 app with an Image and two buttons (previous, next).
I want the source of image to be changed whenever user click on next or previous button.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've just created the two buttons and Image in Xaml. As i said before i am new to programming and thus have no idea of how to do that on button click event.:/

Answer (score 0):

Supposing in the XAML your Image element is called `myImage` you can change the associated source like this:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("yourImagePath", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: Receiving this error- 

Img2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/pic1.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));   
        
 The type or namespace name 'BitmapImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

& When i replace BitmapImage to Image-

'System.Windows.Controls.Image' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Any hope?

Comment: are you using System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage?

Comment: @ChitrarthSharma so add that particular namespace to your cs file.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow as well. I can't put my whole code in comment it says "too long by ** characters"..:O

Comment: Edit it in your original post, but i think your current issue is due to a missing using directive